# How to cancel deploying Google cloud functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I've started to deploy my cloud function with `firebase deploy --only functions:(functionName)`, but 'deploying' status does not end and it's being deployed infinitely until now. I can't delete it because 'delete' button is disabled while deploying the function.

How to I terminate deploying cloud funtion by force?

**Function:**

```
exports.calculate = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const id = (req.query.id).toString();
    let flist = (req.query.fIDs).toString();
    
    const ret = await callCalculate(id, flist);
    
    res.json(ret);
});

async function callCalculate() {...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete the function on cloud and bypass the confirmation prompt, you could add “--force” in your deploy command.
firebase deploy --only functions --project  --token  --force

I certainly hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After re-deploying another cloud function, infinite deploying ended with error logs. I think it have been fallen into deadlock status.